# Java search if a string exists

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am trying to determine if the user entered value already exists in the current array, how to do that?

User entered value to check the variable is 
**accno** and the array to compare to is  **accnums**

This is what i am currently working on

```
public class Randomtopic {

    static BigDecimal[] accbal = new BigDecimal[20];
    static Integer[] accnums = new Integer[20];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayMenu();
    }

    public static void displayMenu() {
        int option, accno;
        double accbal;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Add an account");
        System.out.println("Search an account with the given account number");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice: ");
        option = sc.nextInt();
        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You have choosen to add account");
                addAccount();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("You have choosen to search for an account");
                System.out.print("Enter the Account Number: ");
                accno = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(search(accno, accnums));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please choose an appropriate option as displayed");
        }
        displayMenu();
    }

    public static void addAccount() {
        //String accno;
        int i = 0;
        int accno, input;
        BigDecimal accbala;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        //BigDecimal[] accbal= new BigDecimal[20];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String[] accnums = new String[20];
        int j;
        System.out.print("Enter the account number: ");
        accno = sc.nextInt();
        if (String.valueOf(accno).matches("[0-9]{7}")) {
            System.out.print("Enter account balance: ");
            accbala = sc.nextBigDecimal();
            for (j = 0; j < accnums.length; j++) {
                if (accnums[j] == null )
             break;
         else if(accnums[j].equals(accno))
         {
              System.out.println("Account already exists");
         }
            }
            //System.out.print(j);
            if (j == accnums.length) {
                System.out.print("Account storage limit has reached.");

            } else {

                    accnums[j] = accno;
                    accbala = accbala.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                    accbal[j] = accbala;

            }
            input = accnums[0];
            System.out.println("The value: " + input + " witha a balance of " + accbal[0].toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong NRIC");
        }
        displayMenu();
    }

    public static String search(int accnum, Integer[] numbers) {
        // Integer[] numbers;
        //int key;
        //numbers = accnums;
        // System.out.print("Enter the Account Number: ");        
        for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
            if (numbers[index].equals(accnum)) {
                return String.valueOf(index);
                // System.out.println("The account number exists in this array index :"+index);//We found it!!!
            }
            break;
        }
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

So my problem?
When i enter the accnum for the first time itself i am getting NullPointerException. Tks

Comment: Unless this is `[homework]` I would use a `List` or in this case a `Map<Integer, BigDecimal>`  This would simplify allot of your code and make it slightly faster, just over half your code would not be needed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is indeed homework and i am bound to use only what i am taught..tks any suggestions realted towards that will greatly help me tks

Comment: I would suggest stepping through your code in a debugger to get a better understanding of what it is doing esp. when it doesn't match your expectations.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i have modified my for loop in the addaccount method that is by logically speaking ok right?

Comment: I suggest you tidy up the code. Most IDEs have a tool to do this. It would make the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate or create an array, the values are by default set to null; whenever you iterate over an array of possibly null values, it is required you skip these. For example,

```
for(loop conditions)
        if (numbers[index] != null && (numbers[index].equals(accnum))) {
            return String.valueOf(index);
            //your text goes here;
        }
        break;//I suggest you take this line out of your original code. Your for loop will end this once you have iterated through the entire array, or you will automatically break out if you find the value.
}
```

If you must use an array, then this is the best way to iterate through it. The parenthesis and the && in the if clause prevent you from performing the .equals check if the value of numbers[index] == null - in turn, preventing the null error from being thrown. your only alternative would be to set every value in the numbers[ ] to 0, or some other value, and than skip that value when you iterate. Such would be done with a static final int. However, this is not ideal coding.

Ideally,  you should use an ArrayList - you can then not only make this more efficient, but also, much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `accnums` is filled with `null` values. Check if they are not `null`. I suppose your `NullPointerException` is thrown from `search` method.

Comment: @Baz, where? I don't see anything like null-checking in `search` method.

Comment: does he? This: numbers[index].equals(accnum) probably is the problem.

Comment: @Baz, well, he said that exception thrown when he enters account number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly you have a  number of accounts with associated balance identified by an account number. In this case I would use a Map instead of fiddling with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

when you run your method search first time, yours array `accnums` is filled with null value so when you call line `if ( numbers[index].equals(accnum))` you are trying call equal method on null object


what you can do is change your `accnums` from array to list, and then size will depends on number elements, so it wont have fixed size like your arrays

Comment: ok got that then, in that case i want to continue to the next step.. means dont give ant error then move on... how to get that..?

Comment: instead "if (numbers[index].equals(accnum))" try "if (accnum.equals(numbers[index]))" and at the beginning of yor search method add if (accnum ==null) return -1;

Comment: and get rid off break statement from search method

Comment: i have modified my for loop in the addaccount method that is by logically speaking ok right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code without adding anything in your accnum you are searching.So your accnum contains NULL values.if you change your accnum array into list/hashmap the exception would not arise.